# Online email verification with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, heroku, email-verification

I used mailtrap to run email verification locally, and everything seemed working fine. Once I pushed it to heroku, mailtrap stopped working to send the emails. I've tried a bunch of things including the sendgrid addon, but my account was suspended as I logged in to sendgrid.

Someone is supposed to register, and then get an email to verify their email...It is for a voting platform and I need maximum security.

Answer (score 0):

To send emails in production in your Laravel application you need to use one of the supported drivers listed in the documentation:

```
 "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses", "sparkpost", "log", "array"
```

Mailtrap cannot work in a production environment as users won't receive emails to their inbox. If you need to use sendgrid, they have a detailed tutorial on how to do so using the SMTP driver [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/)

I'm not sure why your account was disabled, but just create a new one, don't use the Heroku sendgrid addon.

Answer (score 0):

Mailtrap tag line is `Safe Email Testing for Staging and Development` so if you are using it in production you may are doing it wrong way.As per your description it is clear why sendgrid has suspended your account but i would recommend you to use postmark or mailgun.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku provide add-ons called "Mailgun Email Validation" try use it.